# Having variable values shown in a textbox in php using sql

Tags: php, sql, variables

I am trying to have a variable from one .php document to display in a textbox in another.  In the process, the value of the variable is going back to a database to grab information relating to the variable.
To be more specific, the user selects a StudentID from a dynamically populated drop down box on the first form, then is taken to another form where the selected StudentID is shown in the first textbox, and other data (such as email address, phone no.) are shown in different textboxes underneath.  This then allows the user to modify the data shown and save it back to the database.

The reason I am running into problems is the variable value is originally coming from a dynamically populated drop down box.  From what I have tried, I do not think the variable is being passed to the second form.  This is because I have tried different variations of code to get the data to show in the textboxes and nothing shows each time.

Here is the code from the drop down box:

```
$query="SELECT StudentID FROM Personal_Details";
$result = mysql_query ($query);
echo '<select name= "StudentID">';
//Printing the list box select command
while($nt=mysql_fetch_array($result)){ /*Array or records stored in $nt*/
echo "<option value=$nt[StudentID]>$nt[StudentID]</option>";
/*Option values are added by looping through the array*/
}
echo "</select>"; //Closing of lost box
?>
```

Being new to this, I am assuming the variable is "StudentID".

If this is the case, this is the code used on the second .php document to get the value of the varaible to display in a textbox, along with the other data:

```
$query=mysql_query("SELECT Email, Phone FROM Personal_Details WHERE StudentID = '$StudentID'") or die(mysql_error());
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($query)) {
   $email = $row[1];
   $phone = $row[2];
}
?>
```

(There are some html code here to set up the form.  I skipped over that and went straight to the code relating to the problem)

```
<form name="modstudent" method="post" action="modstudent2.php">
Student ID: <input name="StudentID" type="text" value="<?php printf("%s",$StudentID);?>"><br>
Email: <input name="email" type="text" value="<?php printf("%s",$email);?>"><br>
Phone: <input name="phone" type="text" value="<?php printf("%s",$phone);?>"><br>
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

UPDATE

The problem seems to be the variable from the first page not being passed over to the second page.  To make sure it was a variable problem, a fixed value was substituted into the code below:

```
$query=mysql_query("SELECT Email, Phone FROM Personal_Details WHERE StudentID = '/StudentID-here/'") or die(mysql_error());
```

What needs to change so the variable can be passed over?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`echo "<option value=".$nt[StudentID].">".$nt[StudentID]."</option>";`   or use `<option value=echo($nt[StudentID])>echo($nt[StudentID])</option>;`

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried both suggestions and neither worked. Could it be something to do with the

'echo '<select name= "StudentID">''

line?